# How to get Image from JSON using Glide

Tags: java, android, json, android-glide

I am getting an error after running the app, in this line

```
String string=response.getString("url");
```

Android studio asked me to create a try and catch mtd, but that's not working. What will be the correct way?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  }
  private void loadMeme() {
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();

    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    String url = "https://meme-api.herokuapp.com/gimme";
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, null,
      new Response.Listener < JSONObject > () {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
          String string = response.getString("url");
          ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.shareImageView);
          Glide.with(MainActivity.this).load(url).into(imageView);
        }
      },
      new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
      });
    // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
    queue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try accessing UI elements on `Main Thread`.

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        try {
          //  Block of code to try
          loadMeme();
        }
       catch(Exception e) {
        //  Block of code to handle errors
          System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
    private void loadMeme() throws
    {
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();

        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        String url ="https://meme-api.herokuapp.com/gimme";
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,url,null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        String string=response.getString("url");
                        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.shareImageView);
                        Glide.with(MainActivity.this).load(url).into(imageView);
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    }
                });
// Add the request to the RequestQueue.
        queue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    }
```